# Is it a bad practise to not return anything from js function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been using react for a while and I have observed that I don't usually return anything from function rather just call function, change global variables and so on..

For example consider my [index.js file in react app](https://github.com/irohitb/Elucidata/blob/master/src/container/mainHome.js)

Here I have this function which formats data for the graph

```
 graphDataFormating = () => {  
      let m = 0
      let arrayPush = []
      let data = this.state.data["groups"]
      let Datalength = this.state.data["groups"].length  
      this.graphdata = []
        if (!this.state.optionalTask)   Datalength = 1
        for (let i=0; i<Datalength; i++) {
            for (let j=0; j<data[i]["peaks"].length; j++) {
                  arrayPush = []
                for (let k=0; k<data[i]["peaks"][j]["eic"]["rt"].length; k++) {
                    if (this.state.filterIntensity < data[i].peaks[j]["eic"]["intensity"][k] && this.state.filterRt < data[i].peaks[j]["eic"]["rt"][k]) {
                        arrayPush.push({
                            y: (data[i]["peaks"][j]["eic"]["intensity"][k]/1000),
                            x: data[i]["peaks"][j]["eic"]["rt"][k]
                        })
                    }
                }
                this.graphdata[m] = arrayPush
                m++
            }
      }

      this.setState({graphData: this.graphdata})
    }
```

Here, I am not returning anything rather changing my global variables (like   this.graphdata[m]) or state  `this.setState({graphData: this.graphdata})`

Now, I call this function multiple times in my programme

```
  userFilterData = (event) => {
    this.setState({[event.target.name]: event.target.value}, () => {
        this.graphDataFormating()
    })
  }


  resetData = () => {
    this.setState({  filterIntensity: -1, filterRt: -1}, () => {
        this.graphDataFormating()
    })
  }

  changetask = () => {
      this.setState({ optionalTask: !this.state.optionalTask}, () => {
        this.graphDataFormating()
      })
```

but all the functions, I have created including the `graphDataFormating()`, I haven't returned anything even for once.

and since I guess if we don't return anything from js function, it will automatically return undefined? hence I believe all the functions above are returning undefined.

**With this, I have two questions,**

Is it a bad practise to not return anything from the function?

If you were to improve this code, what suggestion would you give?

Comment: I don't believe there's an obligation to return values from any of your functions?

Comment: @AJC24 I know there isn't any obligation but talking about practise, like if I interview, do task for my job application. Should I  prefer to think in a way my function return something or it doesn't matter?

Comment: Nothing wrong with a function that doesn't return anything.  I would create some shortcut variables to those inner objects/arrays to reduce the amount of typing that you have to do inside your nested loops to make your code more readable.

Comment: Unless you expect a return there is no reason it must explicitly have one

Comment: Functions **always** return a value. In JavaScript, if **no return value is specified**, the function will **return undefined** by default.  I think there is no best practice for it.

Comment: `Is it a bad practise to not return anything from the function?` do you *need* to return something? I suppose a function that's `function add(a, b) { a + b }` is quite useless and you probably want to return that result but, say, a log function doesn't need to return result. So whether you want to return something or not would vary on circumstances.

Comment: Your function(s) are fine. If you don't need a return value then you don't need to implement one. It's not bad practice to just have methods that perform a function without returning anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes** and **No**

Truthfully it depends.

If you're utilizing methods to alter your state in a state-based application, there's nothing wrong with not returning anything from a function. The priority in that scenario is on completing an `action` rather than the manipulation of data. You're basically saying *"Hey Application, this has changed! Rerender!"*

If, however, you find yourself manipulating data (an array or an object) that *is not* part of state, and by virtue of that not reporting an `action`, it is best to follow the [functional programming paradigm](https://medium.com/@zfrisch/understanding-functional-programming-in-javascript-f3477cde7432), and instead of mutating that data, to create a new entity of the same data type, populate it, and return it.

Answer (score 1):

As you asked what can you improve in that code I'd suggest to replace `for (let j=0; j<data[i]["peaks"].length; j++)` with `for (let j of data[i]["peaks"])` I think it's nicer form of looping through array.

Comment: I prefer using `simple for` instead of `for in` or `for of` but thanks

Answer (score 1):

No, its fine.

The only suggestion would be to try to use `.map` on arrays instead of a triple for loop and push, but what you have looks pretty much fine to be honest.

Comment: You mean functional programming?

Answer (score 0):

As per [specifications](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined#Description), "A function returns undefined if a value was not returned."
To answer your questions:

1) "Is it a bad practice to not return anything from the function?" No. A function returning `undefined` can be thought of as a "procedure" in other languages, i.e. a subroutine that may have some side effects but doesn't return any value.

2) "If you were to improve this code, what suggestion would you give?" Nothing related to functions returning `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old, but I came across it today and thought I'd add.

It's not *wrong*, but there's benefits in doing it the other way.

If you refactored your code to pass in and return like this:

```js
getFormattedData = (data, filterIntensity, filterRt) => {
  let m = 0;
  let arrayPush = [];
  let data = data['groups'];
  let Datalength = data['groups'].length;
  const graphdata = [];
  if (!this.state.optionalTask) Datalength = 1;
  for (let i = 0; i < Datalength; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < data[i]["peaks"].length; j++) {
      arrayPush = [];
      for (let k = 0; k < data[i]["peaks"][j]["eic"]["rt"].length; k++) {
        if (filterIntensity < data[i].peaks[j]['eic']['intensity'][k] && filterRt < data[i].peaks[j]['eic']['rt'][k]) {
          arrayPush.push({
            y: (data[i]['peaks'][j]['eic']['intensity'][k] / 1000),
            x: data[i]['peaks'][j]['eic']['rt'][k],
          });
        }
      }
      graphdata[m] = arrayPush;
      m++;
    }
  }

  return graphdata;
};
```

You could then test this function without your state being touched, and with as many options as you like.

It also seems like then you maybe don't even need to set the `filterIntensity` and `filterRt` states.

```js
resetData = () => {
  this.setState({
    graphdata: this.getFormattedData(
      this.state.data,
      -1,
      -1,
    ),
  })
}
```